# Sqlite select email column from content provider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to select some data from sqlite, where the column represents an email address.

My query is like this:

```
    Cursor countCursor = mContentResolver.query(
            SubscribeContract.SubscribeEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{"count(*) AS count"},
            "user = ? ",
            new String[]{ userChatID },
            null);
```

But it's returning nothing.

Querys on sqlite3 terminal is returning ok.

```
sqlite> select count(*) as count from subscribe where user = 'brunox17_7a84e0c5e635fb571b32f5be9d55dd0b734c2f57@boo-app.com';
```

### count

21

I think the problem is because the column type is text, and I cant put quotes surrounding the selection arguments.

Comment: nothing return means any error getting or countCursor containing empty result?

Comment: countCursor contain empty result.

Comment: in your record have that email address in any of the record?, also try this way "user='"+userChatID+"'" instead of "user=?"

Comment: yes, have the record with the email, i can get the result in terminal using sqlite3. I already tried "user='"+userChatID+"'", and it's not working too.

Comment: Well I find the error. That's happing why the column has an character in upcase, and when i query it, it's all in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

What API version are you testing on? The parametrized queries are supported from API11.

You can try the `getCount()` method on the `Cursor` object without specifying any where clause.

Comment: My problem is not to get the result from the cursor. That's I'm doing ok. The problem here is the cursor returning nothing.

Comment: Some content providers allow only actual columns as columns.

Comment: If I dont put the selection, the cursor returing ok, so I think that's not a problem.